# Getting HTTPS web interface for transmission with Lighttpd reverse proxy

Tags: debian, reverse-proxy, transmission, lighttpd

i'm trying to get HTTPS web interface for transmission. Currently i can access transmission web interface with http://myip:8081
and what i want is to connect with https://myip/transmission . i already setup my lighttpd with TSL/SSL so i can access to default index page at https://myip

I enabled mod_proxy

```
lighty-enable-mod proxy
```

Therefore, in /etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled, i have a 10-proxy.conf which is actually a symlink to /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-proxy.conf, and this file contains :

```
server.modules   += ( "mod_proxy" )
```

then in lighttpd.conf i added :

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:443" {
    ssl.engine  = "enable"
    ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/cert.pem"

    ssl.cipher-list = "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM"
    ssl.honor-cipher-order = "enable"
}

$HTTP["url"] == "^/transmission/" {
        proxy.server = ("" => ( (
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => 8081 
        ))
  )
}
```

Then I reloaded lighttpd config

```
service lighttpd force-reload
```

Conf Syntax is OK but when i  want to access to https://myip/transmission/ I've got a 404 not found page.

Comment: From your question it is not entirely clear whether the lighttpd is not in the same server as your app. It might be worthwhile also to detail how you enabled mod_proxy

Comment: Lighttpd is on same server as transmission app. I enabled lighttpd with lighty-enable-mod proxy .  And link 10-proxy.conf is is conf-enabled folder.

Comment: Please detail how you enabled mod_proxy and try to add relevant access error logs generated my lighthttpd.

Comment: I put the commands i used to enable mod_proxy

Answer (score 0):

With the config given in the original question, lighttpd is sending the request to 127.0.0.1 port 8081 as "GET /transmission/ HTTP/1.1".  If the transmission server expects the request to be "/" instead of "/transmission/", then see `proxy.header` `"map-urlpath"` available in lighttpd 1.4.46 and later.  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy